# Poor performance with MySQL 5.7 compared with 5.1 when 3 or more users are connected

Tags: mysql, performance

I inherited a MySQL 5.1 on Win 2008 Server with 20GB Ram installation now in production, and a new MySQL 5.7 Win 2012 Server with 32GB Ram ready for migration. Same data, same apps. Tens of thousands of tables, 80% are MyISAM, the other 20% Innodb. My first tests after copying data to the new server show performance almost dying after 3 or more users get connected thru the apps. No errors on logs, except for a note during service start:

`page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 77296ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time.)`

Already checked some system variables, but I think I need some direction here.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances        8
innodb_page_cleaners                4
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm      0
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct          75
innodb_flush_neighbors              1

innodb_adaptive_flushing            ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm        10
innodb_flushing_avg_loops           30
innodb_log_file_size                48MB
innodb_io_capacity                  200
innodb_io_capacity_max              2000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 will reach end of life in 15 months from now. I would suggest you upgrade to MySQL 8.0 rather than to 5.7.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Why so many tables?  Did the ENGINE change during the migration?  What is the slowest query?  What are the old and new values of `key_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Does innodb_io_capacity of 200 corresponds to the available storage IOPs on the new server? MyISAM has no concurrency for write operations, look at the slow query log after its enabled an look at changing those to innodb.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't want to mess with applications at this time, wich I think would be the case if I migrate to 8.0, don't you think?

Comment: @AndrésLescano That would definitively be the case. I thought that you already were going throught the effort of migrating (to 5.7), so I guessed it could be a good opportunity to migrate to 8.0 right away. Again, 8.0 is a different animal, so take on it with care.

Comment: @WilsonHauck legacy server is an Intel Xeon Silver 4214R CPU @ 2.40 GHz 2.39 Ghz (2 processors), 24GB Ram. New is same processor but with 32GB Ram. No SSD or NVME devices. I'll provide more information as soon as I get it.

Comment: @RickJames The high number of tables is because there is a set of tables for each customer. No changes on engines in migration. I think I don't need to focus on queries yet, since both servers are compared under same applications. key_buffer_size: legacy 0.63GB, new 0.5GB. innodb_buffer_pool_size:  legacy 1243MB, new 2048MB.

Comment: @danblack I haven't done that math yet. I'll do it and share the results here.

Comment: @AndrésLescano - Those are low settings; how much disk space is being used?  Are other applications running on the same servers?

Comment: @RickJames there is plenty of disk space. No other applications run on these servers.

Comment: @AndrésLescano - (re disk space used by the tables) If the tables are bigger than the settings, I will point out that they needed to be increased.

Comment: @RickJames which settings do you recommend to increase? Is there any formula you could provide for calculating the recommended value?

Comment: @AndrésLescano - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Comment: @RickJames thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have an excel with the additional info. How or where should I post it?

Comment: Attach in email to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com  please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sure do. Tks.

Comment: Suggested our 20 Global Variable Suggestions analysis.  Waiting on feedback.

Comment: @WilsonHauck a test with MySQL 8.0 resulted in no performance problems. Long shot, considering 8.0 as a different animal as Theimpaler mentioned. Case closed by now... thanks for all the ideas.

Comment: Great, Please make contact as needed.  Here to assist.